# error with check50 while i got no error when i actully use it

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50

I was trying to submit my finance code to finish my week 9 in harvard course but for a reason the check50 get error when logging in while i got nothing the error is :( logging in as registered user succceeds Cause application raised an exception and here is my code

```
import os

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from datetime import datetime

from helpers import apology, login_required, lookup, usd

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response


@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""

    list = db.execute("SELECT stocks FROM stock WHERE username =(SELECT username FROM loged_in)")
    stocks = int(list[0]['stocks'])
    result = lookup('NFLX')
    price = int(result['price'])
    total = price * stocks

    """ , stocks, price, total """
    return render_template("indix.html", stocks=stocks, price=price, total=total)


@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""

    if request.method == "POST":
        list = db.execute("SELECT username FROM loged_in")
        name = list[0]['username']
        stock = request.form.get("stock_name")
        result = lookup(stock)
        shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
        price = int(result['price']*shares)
        list2 = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username = ?", name)
        wallet = int(list2[0]['cash'])


        if not result:
            return apology("sorry this symbol doesnt exist")

        elif shares < 1:
            return apology("please enter a positive number")

        elif price < wallet:
            wallet -= price
            list3 = db.execute("SELECT stocks FROM stock WHERE username = ?", name)
            stocks = int(list3[0]['stocks'])
            newstocks = stocks + shares

            """ return render_template("test.html", name = newstocks) """

            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE username = ?", wallet ,name)

            db.execute("UPDATE stock SET stocks = ? WHERE username = ?", newstocks ,name)
        else:
            return apology("sorry you dont have enough money")

        done = (f"you bought {shares} shares from NFLX")

        time = datetime.now()

        now = (f"{time.year}/{time.month}/{time.day} Time={time.hour}:{time.minute}")

        db.execute("INSERT INTO history (username, done, time) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", name, done, now)

        return render_template("thank.html")

    else:
        return render_template("buying.html")

@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
    """Show history of transactions"""

    list = db.execute("SELECT username FROM loged_in")
    name = list[0]['username']

    list2 = db.execute("SELECT done FROM history WHERE username = ?", name)

    list3 = db.execute("SELECT time FROM history WHERE username = ?", name)

    times = []
    names = []

    i = 0
    for n in list2:
        names.append(list2[i]['done'])
        times.append(list3[i]['time'])
        i += 1

    number = len(names)

    return render_template("history.html", name = names, number = number, time = times)


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """ Log user in """

    # Forget any user_id

    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        #DELETE the last log in

        db.execute("DELETE FROM loged_in")

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        name = request.form.get("username")

        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
        db.execute("INSERT INTO loged_in (username) VALUES(?)", name)

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    """Log user out"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # Redirect user to login form
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    """Get stock quote."""
    if request.method == "POST":

        qoute = request.form.get("quote-name")
        final = lookup(qoute)
        if final:
            return render_template("quoted.html", final=final)
        else:
            return apology("sorry this symbol doesnt exist")

    else:
        return render_template("quote.html")


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirm = request.form.get("confirmation")

        if not password or not name or not confirm:
            return apology("please fill all the empty placeholders")

        if password != confirm:
            return apology("your passowrd is not the same")

        list = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users;")
        username = []

        i = 0
        for n in range(len(list)):
            username.append(list[i]['username'])
            i += 1

        for names in username:
            if names == name:
                return apology("sorry this name already exist")

        hash_password = generate_password_hash(password)
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(?, ?)", name, hash_password)
        db.execute("INSERT INTO stock (username, stocks) VALUES(?, 0)", name)

        return render_template("login.html")

    else:
        return render_template("register.html")


@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
    """Sell shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        list = db.execute("SELECT username FROM loged_in")
        name = list[0]['username']
        stock = request.form.get("stock_name_sell")
        result = lookup(stock)
        shares = int(request.form.get("shares_sell"))
        price = int(result['price']*shares)
        list2 = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username = ?", name)
        wallet = int(list2[0]['cash'])

        time = datetime.now()

        now = (f"{time.year }/{time.month}/{time.day} Time={time.hour}:{time.minute}")


        if not result:
            return apology("sorry this symbol doesnt exist")

        elif shares < 1:
            return apology("please enter a positive number")

        else:
            list3 = db.execute("SELECT stocks FROM stock WHERE username = ?", name)
            stocks = int(list3[0]['stocks'])
            if stocks >= shares:
                newstocks = stocks - shares
            else:
                return apology("you dont have enough shares to sell")
            wallet += price

            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE username = ?", wallet ,name)

            db.execute("UPDATE stock SET stocks = ? WHERE username = ?", newstocks ,name)

            done = (f"you sold {shares} shares from NFLX")

            db.execute("INSERT INTO history (username, done, time) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", name, done, now)

        return render_template("thank.html")

    else:
        return render_template("sell.html")
```

sry for the long code but i just note that the problem maybe is not in login because harvard gave me that code already i just add the sql one only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks to be in `index`. `register` ultimately redirects to `index`; a newly registered user has no stock holdings. The `SELECT` won't return any rows so this line `stocks = int(list[0]['stocks'])` will produce an error. Beware, hardcoding the lookup of `NFLX` is likely to produce errors with the checker too. To emulate what `check50` does, register a new user and login. IMO it is asking for trouble (and it is unnecessary) to modify the supplied login.